# How to use laravel auth for admin and user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to use laravel auth for admin and user.
I am using php artisan make auth but it creating on common authentication.

Comment: Use multiauthentication.You can get more tutorial of multi authentication on google.

Comment: Not sure if you are mixing up "authentication" and "authorization". Authentication makes sure `UserX` really is `UserX`. Your admins and users can "authenticate" via the same route/login form. "Authorization" makes sure `UserX` can't call `ActionY` because he's a regular user and not an admin. There's a manual page on [Laravel Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization), see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication and authorization is different things; laravel Auth only used for authentication to check,whether the user login or not, and authorization means to check whether the user have permission or not to access the resource. So you have to make UAC role for admin and user. There are many package available for role and permission you can go through this https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0